# Uniqueness class for higher-order heat-type equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

I am studying the *Volume 3 (Theory of Differential Equations)* of the book *[Generalized Functions](https://books.google.it/books/about/Theory_of_Differential_Equations.html?id=Hq7iBQAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y)* written by I. M. Gel'Fand and  G. E. Shilov. In particular, I'm interested in the results conerning the uniqueness classes (*Chapter 2*). It seems that such results are quite general and I'm trying to apply the same tools to the following:

\begin{cases}
\partial_t v(t,x,y)\, = \, \partial_x^4v(t,x,y)+\partial_y^2v(t,x,y)  \quad 
\text{on }\mathbb{R}^2_T;\\
v(0,x,y)=0 \quad \text{on }\mathbb{R}^2,
\end{cases}

where $t \in [0,T]$. If I have undrstood the trick, the uniqueness class depends on reduced order $p$ of a system and it consists of the functions described by inequalities of the form
\begin{equation}
|v(x)|<k_1\cdot\exp[k_2\cdot|x|^p],
\end{equation}
with $k_1, k_2$ constants.

Now, it is not clear to me how these arguments could be applied to the problem above. Is simply $p=4$? Is there any reduction that I can't see? Are the two different derivatives (one with respect to $x$, one with respect to $y$) a problem?